# How to get Modern(21+) Electron to work with ZeroMQ 5.3.1?

Tags: electron, zeromq-js

My goal is to compile a running app,
but the solution could be twofold;

Originally, I was using Electron 26.2.2, and kept receiving the error

```
Error: No native build was found for platform=win32 arch=x64 runtime=electron abi=116 uv=1 libc=glibc node=18.16.1 electron=26.2.2
```

After some digging, I found a github [issue](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/issues/476#issuecomment-896658382) showing what the precompiled binaries were to download.

So I swapped my Electron Version to 21.2.3 as mentioned in the code, and run into a different error after executing a line `socket.send(command);`

```
[ERROR:node_bindings.cc(146] Fatal error in V8: v8_ArrayBuffer_NewBackingStore When the V8 Sandbox is enabled, ArrayBuffer backing stores must be allocated inside the sandbox address space. Please use an appropriate ArrayBuffer::Allocator to allocate these buffers.
[ERROR:crashpad_client_win.cc(844)] not connected
```

I've attempted to run `npm rebuild zeromq --runtime=electron --target=21.2.3`, and also tried targeting `26.2.2`.

I think I could be running into a zeromq error, but I've seen some posts mentioning they've been able to run with later versions of Electron, which doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Ended up swapping to 6.0.0 beta 19 and it worked fairly easily